# a.active what deactivates an active link?

Tags: css, jqtouch

some examples..

```
#jqt .back.active {
-webkit-border-image: url(img/back_button_clicked.png) 0 8 0 14;
}

<a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
```

and

```
#jqt ul li a.active, #jqt ul li a.button {
background-color: #676c96; 
color: #fff;
}

<ul class="individual">
<li><a href="javascript:cart('0','empty')">Cancel</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:placeOrder()" >Place order now</a></li>
</ul>
```

when either of these are pushed the active state does not turn off. Any quirks why or a way to force the deactivation?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly confusing question. `a:active` selects the link when it's in the active state; `a.active` is a class, presumably added and removed by javascript. You haven't posted your JS, so it's hard to say, but it sounds like either there's a bug in there, and it's not removing the `active` class properly from the elements, or, in your stylesheet you meant to use `:active`.

Comment: Yeah, that is weird. Not sure what the developer was trying to achieve there, changed .active to :active. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

How about using JQuery, just use specified classes instead of the active state. A snippet of code ive used recently should give you some idea of how it works.

```
    $("#tabMenu > li").click(function () {
        $("#tabMenu > li").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
```